# Convert a Activerecord result with has_one associations into a single hash per record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash, merge, flatten

If I have a result from Activerecord I have a array of hashes, if I have eager loaded has_one associations each record hash has a nested hash of its associated record.

My question is, is there a quick rails method that allows you to merge these nested hashes into a single hash per record?

An analogy would be converting records and there associations into single table rows.

Another analogy would be a converting a hash of nested hashes at n levels into a single level hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Include them in the select clause

```
class User
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
  # street1, street2, city etc
end

profiles = Profile.joins(:user).select("users.*, profiles.*").all
profiles.first.login
```

**Approach 2:**

Use delegation

```
class Profile
  belongs_to :user
  # street1, street2, city etc
  delegate :name, :name=, :email, :email=, :to => :user  
end
```

Comment: Approach 1 looks as if it might work. I thought Activerecord had to return using the model class types obviously not the case.

Answer (score 0):

What about the flatten method? 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000280

Comment: I tried this its fine for arrays but there isn't a method of hashes